# How to parse an 0 decimal to String?

Tags: c#, string, decimal

Why is it when I'm parsing a decimal (0) ToString my string shows as empty when using the method:

```
String somthing = someDecimal.ToString("#")
```

And when I'm using:

```
String somthing = somDecimal.ToString("0.##")
```

The string shows up as `0`?

When I'm looking at the value in the debug mode in both way it's says they have a "0" in them.

Comment: You've already got a thousand or so responses in the last two minutes.  But please also look at the examples in the MSDN documentation for [System.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59095yyw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Decimal.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Between all your replies, and the documentation, you should be completely squared away.  And please be sure to upvote any/all responses you found helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [The "#" Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierD)

> Note that this specifier never displays a zero that is not a
>   significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the string. It
>   will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that
>   is being displayed.

If you want to display digits after your decimal point, you need to use `0.00` instead of `0.##`.

Comment: Tnx for your answer, I was looking for some a page like that. But what makes me confused is why is the debugger showing that the String somthing has the value: "0"
At this point the decimal is already parsed? so it should still "" return?

Comment: @user3401136 You are quite welcome. Please read [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link a few times to understand these specifiers more deep.

Comment: @user3401136 There is no parsing stuff here. In your case, `somthing` is just a string representation (with a specific format) of your `someDecimal` value. When you use `0.ToString("0")`, you can see your string `"0"` in your debugger. If you use `0.ToString("#")`, you can see your string `""` (_empty string_) in your debugger. Which is explained exactly in their documentations.

Comment: Allright, I think I added the decimal into my watch instead of the String, now I see that it has "" yes. that makes it more clearer. Tnx :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a fixed number of decimals after the decimal point, you need to use

```
 String somthing = somDecimal.ToString("0.00")
```

In your example you use the `#` specifier which means 'put here a number if there is a meaningful number'.
It would work if `someDecimal` is `0.01`

```
 decimal somDecimal = 0.01m
 String somthing = somDecimal.ToString("0.##");
```

but not if

```
 decimal somDecimal = 0.01m
 String somthing = somDecimal.ToString("0.#");
```

Answer (score 2):

Because pound "#" means convert to symbol if there is a number. `0` is an "empty" number, so it converts to "".

In fact, in second case, you get `0`, as you imply to show *at least one digit* before dot.

This all is by design convention of C# language.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN: the "#" Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierD)

> The "#" custom format specifier serves as a digit-placeholder symbol.
>   If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where
>   the "#" symbol appears in the format string, that digit is copied to
>   the result string. Otherwise, nothing is stored in that position in
>   the result string. **Note that this specifier never displays a zero that
>   is not a significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the
>   string. It will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the
>   number that is being displayed.**

So if the decimal would be 1 instead of 0 it would be diplayed even with `ToString("#")`.